# And if statements in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a simulation of bees spreading pollen, I was hoping to make it so when a bee visits a flower it changes the colour to blue and the turtle 'bee' gets given a pollen value of +1, then when it has a pollen value of +3 and visits a flower the colour changes to green.

I have tried multiple methods to go about this, if there was an and if statement that would be useful e.g.

```
to pollenate 
ask turtles [
if pollen > 3
and if pcolor = yellow or blue [ 
set pcolor white
set pollen pollen - 3
]
]
end
```

I'm not sure if and statements exist though.

so I tried with when the turtles have a pollen count of higher than 3 they change color, then tried the code below but keep getting an error message.

```
to pollenate
ask turtles with [ color = white ] [
if pcolor = blue
[set pcolor = green
set pollen pollen -3
]
]
end
```

I keep getting the error 'Set expected 2 inputs'

any help on either approach would be greatly appreciated, or if i'm doing the whole thing wrong please let me know haha.

Comment: does changing it to `set pollen pollen - 3`, with a space after the minus sign, fix it? if you write `-3` NetLogo will think you mean "the number negative 3", not "subtract 3"

Comment: as for the `if` part of this, try `if pollen > 3 and (pcolor = yellow or pcolor = blue)`. `or` expects a complete, self-contained reporter on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answers to your two questions.

(1)  "and if " can be accomplished by using a logical AND in the test. I **HAD** to use parentheses around the color tests that were connected by OR and then AND that to the pollen > 3 test. As in mathematics, the inner parentheses are evaluated first. I prefer to use parentheses around all logical tests   Like ( pollen > 3) -- it's not required but I find it much easier to read.

```
to pollenate 
ask turtles [
    if (pollen > 3) and ((pcolor  = yellow) or (pcolor = blue))
            [ 
               set pcolor white
               set pollen pollen - 3
           ]
]
end
```

you could use a test for pcolor being found in a list of colors too, like this;

```
to pollenate 
ask turtles [
    if (pollen > 3) and (member? pcolor [yellow blue] )
            [ 
               set pcolor white
               set pollen pollen - 3
           ]
]
end
```

As to your second question, the working version would be

```
o pollenate
ask turtles with [ color = white ] [
if pcolor = blue
[set pcolor = green
set pollen pollen - 3
]
]
end
```

Didn't see the difference?   I put a space on both sides of the minus sign, otherwise Netlogo sees three parameters:  pollen,  pollen, and -3  instead of two you want,namely  pollen and (pollen - 3).